# The distance is attained by a unique point

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Theorem:

Let $K$ be a convex and closed subset of a Hilbert space $X$ and $x \in X$. Then there is a unique $y_x \in K$ such that $$\|x-y_x\|=d(x,K):=\inf \{\|x-y\|: y \in K \}$$

Remarks:

- if $K$ is not closed then the distance $d(x,K)$ isn't attained  in general.

If for example $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $D(0,1)=\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2: \|y\|_2 <1\}$ and $x=(2,0)$ then $d(x,K)=1$ and is attained at the point $(1,0) \notin K$.

Could you explain me how we deduce that $d(x,K)=1$ ?

- if $K$ isn't convex then the uniqueness isn't satisfied.

  Could you explain me why?
- If $A \subset \mathbb{R} (\neq \varnothing)$ then there is a sequence $(a_n) \in A$ such that $a_n \to \inf A$ .

From the last remark we have that there is a sequence $(y_n) \in K$ such that $\|x-y_n\| \to d(x,K)$.

If we apply the last remark don't we get that there is a $y_n \in K$ such that $y_n \to \inf K$ ? How do we conclude that $\|x-y_n\| \to d(x,K)$ ?

Firstly we want to show that $(y_n)$ is Cauchy and since $X$ is a complete metric space it will converge to a $y \in X$, i.e. $\|y_n-y\| \to 0$ and since $K$ is closed we will have that $y \in K$.

In order to show this we will use the Parallelogram law $\|x-y\|^2+\|x+y\|^2=2 \|x\|^2+2 \|y\|^2$. But what $x$ and $y$ do we have to use?

Comment: "if $K$ isn't convex then the uniqueness isn't satisfied. Could you explain me why?" Take the unit circle, and the point $0$. Then the distance between the circle and $0$ is attained by all the points on the circle

Comment: How do we justify that the circle isn't convex? Will the distance be equal to the radius? Or have I understood it wrong? @Tryss

Comment: notice that I was talking about the circle, not the disk. Or if you prefer, the unit sphere $S=\{ x : \|x\| = 1 \}$. Then it's not convex because if $x\in S$, then $-x\in S$, but $\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}(-x) = 0 \not\in S$ And yes, the distance between $0$ and $S$ is equal to the radius (here $1$)

Comment: @Tryss Ah I see... So we see that it is possible that we have a closed but not convex subset of a Hilbert space for which the distance $d(x,K)$ is not attained, right?

Comment: yes, it's possible, but only in infinite dimentional spaces. Take $K =\{(1+\frac{1}{n})e_n \}$, then it's closed and $d(0,K)=1 $ is not attained

Answer (score 0):

> Could you explain me how we deduce that $d(x,K)=1$?

$K$ is the interior of the unit circle about the origin. If $y \in K$, then $d(\mathbf 0,y) < 1$. Now for $x = (0,2), d(\mathbf 0, x) = 2$. By the triangle inequality $d(\mathbf 0, x) \le d(\mathbf 0,y) + d(x, y)$. So
$$d(x, y) \ge d(\mathbf 0, x) - d(\mathbf 0,y) > 2 - 1 = 1.$$
Therefore $d(x, K) \ge 1$. On the other hand for $y = (0, 1 - h), 0 < h < 1$, we have $d(x, y) = 2 - (1 - h) = 1 + h$, so $d(x, K) \le 1 + h$ for all $h > 0$. Hence $d(x, K) \le 1$ as well.

> if $K$ isn't convex then the uniqueness isn't satisfied.
>
> Could you explain me why?

Tryss has already given an excellent example, but let me expand a little more on your question "how do we justify that the circle isn't convex?"

Please don't get so caught up in the statements of the definitions that you lose sight of what they mean: Convex means that the line segment connecting any two points in a set lies entirely within the set: I.e. if you have two points in the set, then every point between is also in the set. Look at the circle. This is clearly not true of it. the chord between two points on the circle is in the interior, not part of the circle itself.

> From the last remark we have that there is a sequence $(y_n)\in K$ such that $\|x−y_n\| \to d(x,K)$.
>
> If we apply the last remark don't we get that there is a $y_n\in K$ such that $y_n\to\inf K$ ? How do we conclude that $\|x−y_n\|\to d(x,K)$ ?

There is no such thing as $\inf K$. $K\subseteq X$, not of $\Bbb R$.

Unfortunately, just knowing $\|x - y_n\| \to d(x, K)$ does not even require $(y_n)$ to have a convergent subsequence. For example, in $\ell_2$ if we let $x = (1, 0, 0, ...)$ and let $K = \{ (\delta_{mn})_n\ |\ m \in \Bbb N, m > 1\}$. That is, $K$ is the remaining elements of the canonical basis of $\ell_2$ other than $x$. Then $d(x, y) = \sqrt 2$ for all $y \in K$, but no non-constant sequence in $K$ converges. (You will note that this $K$ is not convex, so it is not a counter-example to the theorem.)

Comment: Why do we check if $y \in K$ ? Isn't $y$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: The only places either you or I use $y$, it is clearly stated as being an element of $\Bbb R^2$ (or of $K$, which means it is also an element of $\Bbb R^2$). Why would you think it was a *subset* of $\Bbb R^2$ instead?

Comment: A ok... But why do we calculate $d(0,y)$ ?

Comment: I don't calculate it. I just note that it must be $< 1$, which allows me to deduce $d(x, y) > 1$ as shown, and therefore, since $y$ is an arbitrary element of $K$, that $d(x, K) \ge 1$.

Comment: From the triangle inequality we have that $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) \Rightarrow d(x,y) \geq d(x,z)-d(y,z)$, right?
$$$$
Then for $z=0$ we have $d(x,y)\geq d(x,0)-d(y,0)=d(0,x)-d(0,y)$.
$$$$
Why can we pick $x=(2,0)$ although it isn't contained in $K$ ?

Comment: I didn't pick $x = (2,0)$. YOU did! I was responding to the example you gave. Please reread your own post. Also, the triangle inequality holds everywhere in $\Bbb R^2$, not just in $K$.

Answer (score 0):

If $K$ is not convex then we do not have in general a unique $y_x$:
[image]